Is a continuous automorphism of a locally compact topological group necessarily a homeomorphism?
Given a locally compact abelian group $A$, let $p$ be an automorphism of its underlying group $A$ that is also a continuous map with respect to topology of $A$.
Then is it true that $p$ is a homeomorphism? Which is same as saying $p$ is a closed map.
In cases of real numbers  with additive structure, the above assertion is valid by Cauchy functional equation. In case of discrete topology it is valid. I cannot give a counterexample.

This may be helpful. https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.05801

Do you assume Hausdorff and 2nd countable?

@MoisheKohan  For"locally compact ", I mean Hausdorff and locally compact. It's Ok if you prefer second countable.

Without 2nd countable assumption the claim is false.

And with the 2nd countable assumption, the claim is true, you do not even need the abelian assumption. It is a consequence of the Arens lemma. You should decide what assumptions you are making.

@MoisheKohan It is better to give a counter-example, without assumption of second countable condition. A quick search tells me what Arens lemma is, but I still could not provide a counter-example.

Here is an example. Let $G_1$ be countably infinite product of $S^1=SO(2)$'s with the product topology. This is a compact (Hausdorff) group. Let $G_2$ be the same group, but with discrete topology. Let $G=G_1\times G_2$ (with the product topology). This group is locally compact and Hausdorff.  (Disjoint union of continuum of copies of $G_1$ with the coproduct topology.) The group $G_1$ admits a continuous injective endomorphism
$$
f_1: (z_1, z_2,....)\mapsto (1, z_1, z_2,....)
$$
Split $G_2$ as the product $S^1\times G'_2$, where $G'_2$ is, of course, isomorphic to $G_2$ via the isomorphism given by
$$
f_2: (1, w_1, w_2...,)\in \{1\}\times G_2' \to (w_1, w_2,...) \in G_2
$$
Now, construct a group isomorphism $G\to G$ by sending $G_1\times S^1\times G'_2$ to itself via the shift of the middle discrete factor to the first (compact) factor of $G_1$ and using the above homomorphisms $f_1, f_2$ on $G_1$ and $G_2'$. It is clear that the resulting isomorphism is continuous but its inverse is not.
